# How to open custom phone authentication view controller in FirebaseUI?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I have created a custom phone authentication which should replace the default phone authentication.

```swift
let authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()
// You need to adopt a FUIAuthDelegate protocol to receive callback
authUI?.delegate = self
let providers: [FUIAuthProvider] = [
    FUIEmailAuth(),
    FUIPhoneAuth(authUI:FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()!),
    FUIGoogleAuth(),
    FUIFacebookAuth()]
authUI?.providers = providers
```

As shown in above code, I have default phone authentication of firebaseUI. Is there any way to pass custom controller instead of default one?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.